# RSUs and Requests in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

Based on the free tier in cockroachDB Serverless, 250 Million free RSUs are available.
On that note, **how many requests** can this database handle **within 250M RSUs** approximately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CockroachDB Serverless has some documentation that goes over some of the estimates for Serverless usage. There are a couple tables that go over the RU/pricing of certain sized operations.

Serverless Usage Docs: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/learn-about-request-units

If you're looking for something more concrete, I'd recommend running a workload using the `cockroach workload` command, then taking a look at how many RU's it's using based on the queries that are visible.

Workload docs: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cockroach-workload.html